# Innodb Log Buffer: Are contents flushed to disk even for empty transactions?

Tags: mysql

I'm investigating an application bug in which a read-only thread (autocommit=0) runs about 20 SELECT's against various Innodb tables, then [errantly] runs about 3 COMMIT's  (despite no DML run at any point) before disconnecting.

As these threads are run in parallel and creating perhaps 20 COMMIT's per second, I want to know if these "empty" COMMIT's are negatively impacting the server.  About 20% of the server's traffic is writes, but again these particular threads are read-only.

It's my understanding that normally a dirty page is first written to a given thread's local redo buffer, then its copied into the global innodb_log_buffer. We use innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1, so I believe the global buffer is flushed to disk upon each COMMIT- but does that happen even for "empty" COMMIT's like the one I've described? I want to ensure we aren't needlessly flushing to disk here.

I'd appreciate an answer and also an explanation on how to measure the amount of redo log flushing my server is doing.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of mysql are you running?

Comment: version 5.1.73 ,   upgrading to  5.7.17  in a few months

Comment: To add to the variables... MySQL Server 5.1.73 actually includes two different versions of InnoDB, the "built-in" and the "plugin," and they *may* behave differently.  The I/O characteristics of the plugin are overall better than the built-in. http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/innodb-plugin-1.0-en.pdf